# Parse strings like command line arguments with Go

Tags: go, command-line-arguments

How do I take a string and parse it as if it was a series of command line arguments? I want to be able to take a string and parse that with flag and/or pflag. How do I do this?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    flag "github.com/spf13/pflag"
)

func main() {
    command := `unimportant -fb "quoted string"`
    var (
        foo bool
        bar string
    )
    flag.BoolVarP(&foo, "foo", "f", false, "foo")
    flag.StringVarP(&bar, "bar", "b", "default", "bar")

    // Parse command
    os.Args = append(os.Args, "-fb", "quoted string")
    flag.Parse()

    fmt.Println(command)
    fmt.Println("foo", foo)
    fmt.Println("bar", bar)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be use the package [`shellwords`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/mattn/go-shellwords) to parse your string into an `argv` of shell words, and then use a command-line parser other than [`flag`](https://pkg.go.dev/flag) or [`pflag`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/spf13/pflag) that supports parsing an arbitrary `argv` (say [`flags`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jessevdk/go-flags), but there are many to choose from.)

```
// Parse  your string into an []string as the shell would.

argv, err := shellwords.Parse("./foo --bar=baz")
// argv should be ["./foo", "--bar=baz"]

...

// define your options, etc. here

...

extraArgs, err := flags.ParseArgs(&opts, argv)
```

Comment: `flag` and `pflag` can both parse an arbitrary `argv`, see [flag.FlagSet.Parse](https://pkg.go.dev/flag#FlagSet.Parse) and [pflag.FlagSet.Parse](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/spf13/pflag#FlagSet.Parse).

Comment: @erdnaxeli — the original question is wanting to take an arbitrary string (as if entered on the command line) and parse it into "words" as the shell would do, producing an `argv`. For instance, the string `foo bar"baz" -o some \file.name".txt"` would be parsed into the words `foo`, `barbaz`, `-o`, and `some file.name.txt`. Then you need to decide whether or not you want to expand globs (you probably do).

Comment: Yes, you are right, my comment is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Regex can use to detect each argument. There are two possible forms for an argument:

1. a group of letters and a negative sign: `[-a-zA-Z]+`
2. something sandwiched between two ": `".*?"`

Information about `regexp` package: https://pkg.go.dev/regexp

Information about `regexp` syntax: https://pkg.go.dev/regexp/syntax@go1.17.6

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`([-a-zA-Z]+)|(".*?[^\\]")|("")`)
command := `unimportant -fb "quoted string"`

allArgs := re.FindAllString(command, -1)

//fmt.Printf("%+v\n", allArgs)

// to remove "
for _, arg := range allArgs {
    if arg[0] == '"' {
        arg = arg[1 : len(arg)-1]
    }
    fmt.Println(arg)
}
```

Output:

```
unimportant
-fb
quoted string
```

Comment: What about escaped quotes like in `unimportant -fb "quoted string \"with\" escaped quotes"`?

Comment: Regex changed in the answer: `([-a-zA-Z]+)|(".*?[^\\]")|("")`